# Material exact color

Tags: materials, shaders, color

I am using Blender to modify some .svg icons for a UI, and I need them to be a certain plain color, with no shading. How could I go about achieving this? I am using Cycles, and if I use a Diffuse material the lighting changes the color, and if I use an Emission material it comes out much brighter. I need it to be the exact RGB values in the material.
Thanks!

Comment: Overkill. Why are you using a full 3D modelling suite to edit some SVG files, and a complex unbiased raytracing solution to obtain flat colors? Why not use say Inkscape, or any other vector editing software?

Comment: Don't use cycles

Comment: blender internal would be better if you need to do this in blender, set the material as "shadeless", and also you could need to use a "raw" setting for the scene > color management > render > view.

Comment: see this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89395/is-there-a-way-to-render-to-png-as-raw-pixels-without-converting-color-space-t

Comment: Thanks! I got it in the end using blender internal. If anyone wants to submit an answer I'll accept it.